# Alternative update server for Chrome extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension, auto-update

On the page http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/autoupdate.html it is described how to set auto-update for an extension. Is there any possibility to set an alternative *.crx location, when the first server is offline?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. But there are a number of things you can do to improve uptime. You could host the crx and xml on a CDN for example.